# PL/SQL procedure to accept an item_num and report its description,price,and on_hand quantity is not working

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a homework assignment in my database management class.  We were given the option of using Oracle SQL Developer on campus computers, or using SSH Secure Shell (I am using the later).  I am to write a procedure which accepts an item_num and reports its description, price, and on_hand quantity.  (Btw:  all of these come from a table named "item".)  My professor has said that a few commands (listed above the procedure) must proceed the procedure.  My code:

```
serveroutput on; 
accept item_num prompt 'Enter a item_num: '; 
exec reports_item_info();

create or replace procedure reports_item_info (i_item_num in
item.item_num%type) as
i_description item.descripton%type;
i_std_price item.std_price%type;
i_on_hand item.on_hand%type;

begin
select description,std_price,on_hand
into i_description,i_std_price,i_on_hand
from item
where item_num = i_item_num;

dbms_output.put_line(rtrim(i_description))||' '||
    (rtrim(i_std_price))||' '||(rtrim(i_on_hand))

end;
/
```

I know that something isn't right, because it doesn't work.  How could I alter it, so that it will work?

Comment: Your procedure has a parameter. But in your shell script you are not passing that parameter - your item_num. Try this: exec reports_item_info(tem_num);

Comment: `SSH` is not a program to query an Oracle database - it is a program to securely login to a remote server and once you have access to the server then you can use a program on that server (typically `sqlplus`) to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the usage of `dbms_output.put_line` make it as

```
dbms_output.put_line(rtrim(i_description)||' '||rtrim(i_std_price)||' '||rtrim(i_on_hand));
```

by removing redundant parentheses.

Put a semi-colon at the end of this statement of course.

And there's a problem in spelling of the column `description`.

Then, use the following :

```
 SQL> set serveroutput on;

 SQL> CREATE TABLE item(
                  item_num    varchar2(50),
                  description varchar2(100),
                  std_price  number(10,2),
                  on_hand    varchar2(100)
 );

 SQL> INSERT INTO item VALUES ('AH74, BR23, CD33','abc',15.75,'defgh');

 SQL> COMMIT;

 SQL> create or replace procedure reports_item_info(i_item_num in item.item_num%type) as
    i_description item.description%type;
    i_std_price   item.std_price%type;
    i_on_hand     item.on_hand%type;
  begin
    select description, std_price, on_hand
      into i_description, i_std_price, i_on_hand
      from item
     where item_num = i_item_num;

    dbms_output.put_line(rtrim(i_description) || ' '|| rtrim(i_std_price)||' '||rtrim(i_on_hand));

  end;
  /

  SQL> accept item_num prompt 'Enter a item_num: '; -- enter   AH74, BR23, CD33   when prompts
  SQL> exec reports_item_info('&item_num'); -- use parameter with quotes

  abc 15.75 defgh

  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: I am still getting the message, "Warning:  Procedure created with compilation errors."

Comment: I have attempted the above code several times, but my procedure will not complete.

Comment: The item#'s in the item table have 2 letters & 2 numbers, i.e. AH74, BR23, CD33.  Whenever put in the commands:  accept item_num prompt  'Enter a item_num: '; execute reports_item_info(&item_num);     this is what happens:  accept item_num prompt 'Enter a item_num: '; Enter a item_number:  SQL> CD33  SP2-0042:  unknown command "CD33" - rest of line ignored.

Comment: @Littlefoot   I figured out why it was not working, and it now works.  Thank you for all of your help.@BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 0):

If you pay attention to what you type, it works; you didn't provide CREATE TABLE so I created it myself.

```
SQL> create table item (item_num    number,
  2                     description varchar2(20),
  3                     std_price   number,
  4                     on_hand     number);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure reports_item_info
  2    (i_item_num in item.item_num%type)
  3  as
  4    i_description item.description%type;
  5    i_std_price   item.std_price%type;
  6    i_on_hand     item.on_hand%type;
  7  begin
  8    select description, std_price, on_hand
  9      into i_description, i_std_price, i_on_hand
 10      from item
 11      where item_num = i_item_num;
 12
 13  dbms_output.put_line(rtrim(i_description) ||' '||
 14                       rtrim(i_std_price)   ||' '||
 15                       rtrim(i_on_hand)
 16                      );
 17  end;
 18  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into item values (1, 'test', 100, 10);

1 row created.

SQL> exec reports_item_info(1);
test 100 10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Your mistakes?

- it is not a DESCRIPTON but DESCRIPTION
- missing semi-colon at the end of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE call
- superfluous parenthesis

**[EDIT]**

Try with this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    item_num number := &enter_item_num_value;
  3  begin
  4    reports_item_info(item_num);
  5  end;
  6  /
Enter value for enter_item_num_value: 1
old   2:   item_num number := &enter_item_num_value;
new   2:   item_num number := 1;
test 100 10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

or

```
SQL> accept itnum prompt 'Enter value : ';
Enter value : 1
SQL> exec reports_item_info(&itnum);
test 100 10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I like the test.  However, the procedure has to accept the input of an item_num.  Where should my code of:  accept item_num prompt 'Enter a item_num: '; go?

Comment: Are your results from Oracle SQL Developer?  Or from SSH?  Currently, I do not have access to Oracle SQL Developer, and I am trying to do it in SSH.  Therefore, it does not work like you have shown above.

Comment: (Sorry, went to sleep). It is SQL*Plus.